# Is an abelian group the sum of a torsion group with a free group?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, direct-sum, torsion-groups

Is an abelian group $G$ always isomorphic to the direct sum of its torsion group $T$ with a free group?

Alternatively, is the quotient $G/T$ always free?

By definition, $T$ consists of all elements in $G$ having finite order. I can see that this is true when $G$ is finitely generated, but I believe it is false in general.

Comment: Have a look at $\mathbb{Q}$ as an additive group.

Comment: The direct product $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is another example. Not only is its torsion-free quotient not free (like $\mathbb{Q}$), its torsion subgroup is not a direct summand.

Comment: The phrase to search for is "mixed abelian groups".

Comment: @IncnisMrsi Why did you remove the (group-theory) tag? Surely that is the most appropriate tag of all! (Moreover, it has more followers than the other tags, which means that the question will not get lost. I would not have spotted this question, and so would not have answered it, if it did not have the group-theory tag.)

Comment: @user1729: I do not care about [tag:group-theory]. If nobody will object in several hours, then you may put it back along specific tags added by me.

Comment: @IncnisMrsi I do not understand your comment - you mean that you do not approve of the tag, or that the topic of group theory is of no interest to you? But in either case, I do not understand why you feel that this tag should be removed.

Comment: @user1729: I mean, do not care whether the (group-theory) is here. You may ignore it: as a Wikipedian émigré I’m accustomed to eliminate overcategorization (i.e. “redundant” upper-level categories), that isn’t necessarily a good approach here.

Comment: It is true if the group is finitely generated (That is the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups)

Answer (score 3):

No. For example, consider $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ under multiplication. The only non-trivial torsion element is $-1$, and quotienting this out you obtain the positive reals under multiplication, $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\setminus\{0\}$. Your task is then to prove that $\mathbb{R}_{>0}\setminus\{0\}$ is not free abelian. Which it isn't.